# How can I more easily save value in txt file to variable? python line.split

Tags: python, split

I have a .txt file with two columns. If the value in the first column matches my criteria then I want to store the value of the second column. This is what I have so far which works but seems silly to store it twice. Any nicer ways of doing this would be appreciated.

```
file = open(nameoffile.txt, 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
    if (line.startswith("something")):
         value = line.split()
         P_point = value[1]
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'to store it twice'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure about "storing twice", but your code is better written as:

```
with open('somefile') as fin:
    points = [line.split()[1] for line in fin if line.startswith('something')]
```